# Can't change desktop background image on Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS

Tags: desktop-environments

I use Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS, 64-bit.

I've been trying to change the desktop background image and... I can not to do it!

The system shows me any possible image (BMP, JPG,PNG, etc.) as grey files in the file menu of the desktop manager.

I can only chose images from the default "ubuntustudio" folder.

Can I fix it, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!!

I could get any background image to my desktop.

The problem was in the way I used to access the images.

The right process is:

1) Open the "Configuration Panel"

2) Go to "Desktop", "Background" Tab.

3) Into the "Folder" box, look for the folder where the image you want to use is.

4) Here was my mistake, the images will appear into the "Configuration Panel" window. Not into the "Folders" box.

5) When you see the images, from the folder you chose into the panel window, just click on the image you want to use as your desktop background.

This chosen image will appear inmediately as your new desktop background.

That's all, folks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already resolved this issue, I hope this helps. I recently installed ubuntustudio 16.04 LTS and I had to open a terminal and type: sudo cp /filepath /usr/share/backgrounds
for each file I wanted to use as my desktop background. By doing this you are invoking the copy command.
/filepath  is the file you want to use, and of course /usr/share/backgrounds is the destination path, the place where my system looks by default for images to use as background. You can also move more than one file at a time

Comment: My bad, copy more than one file at a time. Move (mv) is a whole different command

Comment: you can edit your answer, rather than commenting on it. Please also use appropriate formatting for code. And you might want to explain how to `cp` more than one file at a time :)